# R: row-wise checking for multiple values

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this

[image]

With further rows below. I want to create a column to the right that will have 1 if it matches with a certain value I am checking for row-wise and otherwise it will be 0.
For a single value I have the following code -

```
set.seed(4991)

my_data <- data.frame(ceiling(matrix(runif(100,4,10),ncol = 5)))

comval <- c(5)

my_data$bleh <- as.integer(apply(my_data, 1, function(r) any(comval %in% r)))
```

The output looks like this -

[image]

Which is what I want. Now the issue I am having is that if I have two or more values under 'comval' , for instance,
`comval<-c(5,10)`
I am getting 1 on the 'bleh' column for all columns that either have 5 or 10. The output is like -

[image]

It is like an OR logical operator. I need it to work as an AND logical operator, that is, 'bleh' column will have the value 1 only if all the values in 'comval' are there in the rows.

Also, I am trying to write a function here so I need to take the `length(comval)` as an input and then check for all the values in 'comval' against each row.

Comment: Try to replace `any()` with `all()` in your code. Is it right?

Comment: @DarrenTsai It works for this particular problem. Thank you for that. The problem is when I use all() for different dataset (which I cannot share) I am not getting accurate results. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: Could you give an example to which case `all()` doesn't work for? It's hard to guess the real situation you meet without any data.

Comment: Is your real data non-integer? If so you may be facing precision problems. But as Darren says all we can do is guess without a reproducible example where `all()` fails. Logically, `all` does exactly what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if `length` of `intersect` is equal or greater than 1.

```
my_data$bleh <- as.integer(apply(my_data, 1, function(r) {
    length(intersect(comval, unlist(r))) >= 1
}))
#    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 bleh
# 1   5 10  5  6 10    1
# 2   9  9  5  8  6    1
# 3   5 10  5  5  5    1
# 4  10  8  6  5  8    1
# 5   8  6  7  9 10    1
# 6   5 10  8 10  8    1
# 7   9  8 10  5  7    1
# 8   6  8 10  6  7    1
# 9   5  5  6  6  8    1
# 10 10  5  8  6  8    1
# 11  9 10 10  7  7    1
# 12  6  8  7 10  8    1
# 13  6  9  7  6  9    0
# 14  8  6  6 10  7    1
# 15  9  9  5  7  7    1
# 16 10  9  9 10  6    1
# 17  7 10  5 10  8    1
# 18  9  8 10  9  9    1
# 19 10  8  9  6  8    1
# 20  5  8  6  7  5    1
```